# Change the background color of an input element on focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like to change the background colour of the text input (`.item-input`) when I press a tab key or via mouse -  for some reason focus is not firing?

For example:

```
<tr class="item">
     <td> <input class="item-input" type="text" /> </td>
     <td> <input class="option" type="text" /> </td>
</tr>
```

If .item-input is selected via key or mouse

```
if($('.item-input').is(':focus')) {
    $(this).addClass("input-focus");
}
```

In the css file I have:

```
.input-focus {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Just use pure css https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use plain CSS:

```css
.item-input:focus {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<input class="item-input" type="text" />
```

But if you want to use jQuery, listen to the `focus` event:

```js
$('.item-input').on('focus blur', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("input-focus");
});
```

```css
.input-focus {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="item-input" type="text" />
```

I replaced the `.addClass()` method with the `.toggleClass()` method under the impression that you want the class removed on `blur`.

Comment: Hmm where does `.item-input:focus` come from

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back `.item-input` is the element you are targeting, `:focus` is a pseudo class. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus

Comment: That won't remove the class when the focus is lost, it will remove it when it is focused for the second time.